# Redondear resultado - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, redondeo

¿Cómo puedo redondear los resultados?'''

Conversor de grados entre Fahrenheit a Celsius en multiplos de 10. Intervalos de grados entre 0º - 100º C a 0º - 230º

```
def Fahrenheit_to_Centigrado(g):
    return (g - 32) / 1.8
    
def Centigrado_to_Fahrenheit(g):
    return (g * 1.8) + 32


def centigrados (ini, fini):
    for grados in range (ini, fini+10, 10):
        print("{}ºF--> {}ºC".format(grados,Fahrenheit_to_Centigrado(grados))) 

def fahrenheit (ini, fini):
    for grados in range (ini, fini+10, 10):
        print("{}ºC--> {}ºF".format(grados,Centigrado_to_Fahrenheit(grados))) 


Tipo = input("Salida F/C: ")

if Tipo.upper() == 'C':
    centigrados (0,230)
elif Tipo.upper() == 'F':
    fahrenheit (0,100)
else:
    print("Tipo de entrada incorrecto")`
```

Comment: Si te refieres a la hora de mostrarlos puedes usar `{:.2f}` por ejemplo en vez de `{}` en la cadena del `print()`. Eso indica que lo muestre sólo con dos decimales.

Comment: sería bueno dar más datos que "¿cómo redondeo?". ¿Qué has probado? ¿Qué no te funciona? ¿Cómo quieres que se vea?

Comment: mUCHÍIIISIMAS GRACIAS A TODOS POR VUESTRAS RESPUESTAS. mUY UTILES :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`round()` es una función incorporada disponible en Python. Le devolverá un número flotante que será redondeado a los decimales que se dan como entrada. Si no se especifican los decimales a redondear, se considera como 0, y se redondeará al entero más cercano.

```py
int(round(x))
```

Lo redondeará y lo cambiará a un número entero (como en la segunda y quinta líneas del siguiente código).

Código:

```py
def Fahrenheit_to_Centigrado(g):
    return int(round((g - 32) / 1.8))
    
def Centigrado_to_Fahrenheit(g):
    return int(round((g * 1.8) + 32))


def centigrados (ini, fini):
    for grados in range (ini, fini+10, 10):
        print("{}ºF--> {}ºC".format(grados,Fahrenheit_to_Centigrado(grados))) 

def fahrenheit (ini, fini):
    for grados in range (ini, fini+10, 10):
        print("{}ºC--> {}ºF".format(grados,Centigrado_to_Fahrenheit(grados))) 

Tipo = input("Salida F/C: ")

if Tipo.upper() == 'C':
    centigrados (0,230)
elif Tipo.upper() == 'F':
    fahrenheit (0,100)
else:
    print("Tipo de entrada incorrecto")
```

Ejemplo de resultados:

```
Salida F/C: F
0ºC--> 32ºF
10ºC--> 50ºF
20ºC--> 68ºF
30ºC--> 86ºF
40ºC--> 104ºF
50ºC--> 122ºF
60ºC--> 140ºF
70ºC--> 158ºF
80ºC--> 176ºF
90ºC--> 194ºF
100ºC--> 212ºF
```

Para redondear un número a un decimal:

```py
round(x, 1) # sin un int()
```

Comment: Esta buena la respuesta, pero te pediría agregar el caso con un decimal, para mayor claridad `36.0°C --> 96.8°F`

Comment: @CandidMoe Lo agregué al final de mi respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, si después aplicas `int` los decimales se pierden. A eso apunta mi observación